# Visual Studio 2012 not producing .exe

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, exe

I just installed and tried to build a simple Hello world program, however I can't seem to find the .exe, nor any way in which I can see the program produce the "hello world". Attached are the screenshots of what I am trying to do to build, and the folder in which I believe it should be outputting an .exe

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pd4hM.png
http://i.imgur.com/WK2Hb.png (It isn't in the subfolders either)

Comment: All the output will be in the `Release` directory (as that's your current build configuration) - what's there?

Comment: "This folder is empty"

Also when I try to do anything related to debugging, it returns a pop-up error that there is no executable in the debugging directory.

Comment: Have you actually got any code in the project? We can see that you've got a file open, but the solution explorer isn't showing any code *in the project*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Make sure, that the CPP file is inside the SourceFiles in your project. If it is not, it will not be built.
2. Check the properties of project (especially the General tab) for the output directory for project files.
3. Build your project. Visual Studio informs in Output window, where is the binary, eg.

```
    1>------ Build started: Project: NativeConsoleSketchbook, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
    1>Build started 2012-12-06 09:39:35.
    1>InitializeBuildStatus:
    1>  Creating "Debug\NativeConsoleSketchbook.unsuccessfulbuild" because "AlwaysCreate" was specified.
    1>ClCompile:
    1>  main.cpp
    1>Link:
    1>  NativeConsoleSketchbook.vcxproj -> D:\Dokumenty\Dev\VS\Sketchbook\Debug\NativeConsoleSketchbook.exe
    1>FinalizeBuildStatus:
    1>  Deleting file "Debug\NativeConsoleSketchbook.unsuccessfulbuild".
    1>  Touching "Debug\NativeConsoleSketchbook.lastbuildstate".
    1>
    1>Build succeeded.
    1>
    1>Time Elapsed 00:00:02.81
    ========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Answer (score 1):

Me too got build succeded message but the exe was not generated.

In Visual Studio Solution Explorer pane, right click on the source file and select properties. Make sure it is not set to "**Does not participate in build**"

Change it to the "**C/C++ compiler**" using the drop down list.

[image: source file property page]